# The screen of my Lumia 520 doesn't work properly anymore

Tags: screen

My screen does not work properly.

If I tap on the letter **U** it actually select on **P**  etc.

What should I do now?

Comment: I (rarely) encountered this behavior on my old Lumia 620. I solved it by switching off the phone, then cleaning perfectly the screen with a wet cloth and finally switching on again.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the screen has become damaged in some way - I'd suggest taking it to a service centre